# Изменение значения переменной каждый интервал времени

Tags: c++, время

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь реализовать игру "Тамагочи" (C++, консольное приложение).  С течением времени объект класса тамагочи должен голодать: его уровень голода должен повышаться на единицу за каждую единицу времени (например на +1 за каждые 60 секунд). Как реализовать эту возможность?

Основной интерфейс программы реализован на цикле while: пользователь вводит команды, которые интерпретируются программой как "покормить", "погулять", я не знаю, "поиграть" итд.

Собственно, вопрос из 2-х частей:

1. Как реализовать изменение значения переменной(голод) раз в минуту? Можно ли это сделать современным способом? С++11, там, все дела.
   Единственное, что приходит в голову — создать цикл, который будет работать, пока разница между началом работы цикла и текущим моментом t0-t1 не будет больше 60.
2. Можно ли реализовать это изменение значения на фоне работающего цикла while(общение программы с пользователем) *без* threading? То есть, чтобы мне не приходилось ждать окончания 60-секундного цикла, чтобы ввести команду в консоль.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

1. Можно использовать библиотеку time.h, которая позволяет получать текущее время. Далее написать метод, который будет срабатывать каждую секунду.
2. Да, можно.

Например, можно использовать kbhit() + getch(), чтобы проверять была ли нажата клавиша(Уверен, что есть более элегантный способ)

Примитивный игровой цикл выглядит следующим образом

```
while (true){ 
input(); 
update(); 
render(); 
}
```

в методе Input() ты проверяешь ввел ли пользователь данные или нет. 
В методе update обновляются все данные, например питомец кушает или нет.
В методе render отрисовываешь данные, но если у тебя консольное приложение, то он тебе не нужен.

Советую прочитать книгу Game Programming Patterns(есть перевод на русском). Там очень понятным языком рассказано, как всё происходит. В книге есть глава Game Loop, где как раз и описаны игровые циклы.

Comment: @Rpro, именно в функции `update()` вы в цикле смотрите на всех тамагочи и в зависимости от текущего времени и времени последнего кормления (его запоминаете в структуре, описывающей каждого тамагочи) меняете уровень его голода.

Comment: @avp Но ведь в таком случае функция update() не вызовется до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет какой-нибудь input();
В таком случае, если я отлучусь на длительное чаепитие, мой тамагочи даже не умрет, ведь значение голода не высчитается, пока я не введу что-нибудь в консоль. Верно?

Comment: @Rpro, не верно. Пока вы ничего не вводите время все равно идет. Вы узнаете текущее время после ввода, потом update все вычисляет и сразу потом render рисует результат (уже умерших от голода). Если же вы хотите сидеть и наблюдать, то просто надо модифицировать input так, чтобы он прерывался, скажем раз в секунду, если ничего не введено и возвращал это событие (таймаут). Тогда будете в том же цикле наблюдать весь процесс.

Comment: @avp ура. До прерывания инпута я не догадался. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Ну, мне кажется, что проще всего - в отдельном потоке.

Можно без него, только сделать показатель не переменной, а функцией, которая просто рассчитывает значение исходя из конкретного времени.

Comment: Я не умею в потоки с:
Хорошо, если я, допустим, сделаю показатель функцией, рассчитывающей значение по текущему времени, то я же должен буду эту функцию постоянно вызывать? При чем чаще, чем раз в минуту. Как это реализовать?

Comment: А как вы хотели делать это, если бы переменная меняла свое значение сама, без вашего вмешательства? Вы же не просили, чтобы переменная прерывала цикл - значит, вы знали, что делать с такой переменной...

Answer (score 1):

Как написал оратор выше, можно создать некоторый функционал, который позволит замерять время между вызовами некоторой функции, эту дельту накапливать в переменной типа `float` (или любой другой, в зависимости от используемых функций и библиотек) и при превышения порога в 60 секунд увеличивать значение голода. Такой функционал обычно называют таймером.

[Вот пример с англоязычного stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695288/getting-the-current-time-in-milliseconds-from-the-system-clock-in-windows) для получения времени в Windows.
Пример на псевдокоде для описания выше:

```
SystemTime oldTime, newTime;
GetSystemTime(&oldTime); // для верной инициализации
WORD seconds = 0;
while (true)
{
     //какой-то код
     GetSystemTime(&newTime);
     seconds = newTime.wSeconds - oldTime.wSeconds;
     if (seconds >= 60)
     {
         increaseHungry();
         oldTime = newTime;
     }
 }
```

Вариант в вашем случае может несколько отличаться в зависимости от используемой ОС и библиотек, т.к. у библиотек встречается своя реализация таймеров, например в том же Qt.

Так же в C++11 есть библиотека `<chrono>`, использовать можно в таком же ключе, как и пример с `GetSystemTime()`, [ссылка](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/system_clock/) на пример, в частности используются тип данных `std::time_t` и функция `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` для получения текущего времени.